# Contact in Chile for Chilean e-visa?

Tags: visas, applications, australian-citizens, chile

I’m an Australian trying to apply for a visa to visit Chile for tourism. Application looks all good except for this one part at the end which says I must provide a “Contacto en Chile” (Contact in Chile). Of course I don’t know anyone in Chile because I’m a tourist. Does this mean I’m not allowed to visit Chile? Or is there something I can do here?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you enter the contact details of the (first) place where you’ll be staying?

Comment: I suppose but I need to provide a first and last name. You also must specify your “relationship” with the person and the options are like “brother”, “friend” etc

Comment: @protango There is also an "Unrelated" option

Comment: How long from start to finish did this take and what consulate in Australia did you use?

Answer (score 3):

So I just got my visa approved! Basically yeah I did as a lot of folks suggested and put the hotel details as my "contact in chile". Just had to be a little creative with some of the form fields but I've included a screenshot of how I filled out this form below.

[image]

While I'm here I guess I'll clarify the whole process for any other Australian's doing this because it's really hard to find any info on the process:

### Step 1) Submit your application

Go here: https://tramites.minrel.gov.cl/ and select "Solicitar visa o autorización previa" (Request visa or prior authorization). There is an option to switch the page to English at the top, but it seemed to break things on the website so I recommend doing it in Spanish (this may be fixed in future though)
[image]

### Step 2) Enter your information

Most of the application is quite straightforward, just answer the questions - they will ask about your nationality, passport details, your parents and a few other bits and pieces. There are a few tricky parts which I'll outline below:

- For "País o lugar en el que está realizando la solicitud" (Country or location where you are applying) - you MUST select Australia (Or your passport issuing country) even if you are currently in a different country.
- You can choose which embassy you wish to apply to, I recommend applying to the nearest embassy to you - but contrary to other advice online, you **do not** need to attend an in-person appointment, so don't worry if there's no Chilean embassy near you.
- They check on the income details quite carefully, ensure your payslips/bank statements cover at least 3 months and match the name and address on your application exactly
- For the "contact in chile" see my screenshot above on how to fill this out

### Step 3) Submit your application

Submit and wait patiently, you will get an email confirmation shortly where you can log on and track your application

### Step 4) Pay the fee

After you should receive an email asking to pay $190 AUD (price accurate as of Nov 2023) and was given an Australian bank account to transfer into (BSB/ACC number). I paid the fee and replied with a receipt of the transfer.

### Step 5) Answer any follow up questions and approval

You may or may not be asked some follow up questions about your application via email. I only had one query about my income which was easily resolved. After about a week (from paying) my visa was approved and sent to me as a pdf. The visa itself **must** be physically printed on paper - apparently they will not accept a digital copy. I recommend printing it out and sticking it in your passport (you can cut it down to passport size).

Comment: (+1) I’m not sure whether *physically* sticking anything in a passport should be done by anyone other than an official entity.